# Values of Variable change to N/As after data normalization

Tags: r, normalization, na, minmax

For a polynomial regression, I am supposed to normalize my dataset (GDP Brazil 1960-2017 from world bank data)

using:

```
x= x - min(x)
x= x/max(T)
```

by changing the "x" to our independent variable.

I tried to contact the lecturer with no response and also tried different data sets, but this set is the only one that does not work.

```
##Task 3.1##
##Load Data ##
GDP_Brazil <- read_excel("GDP Brazil.xlsx") 

View(GDP_Brazil)

##Plotting the original Data

G=GDP_Brazil[,3]
Time=GDP_Brazil[,2]

##3.2
##Normalization of data

Time= Time - min(Time)
Time= Time/max(Time)
```

### After running this code, the data is N/A for this variable

After running the code, the outcomes of Variable Time change from [1960,2017] to N/A while it should be between [0,1].

Comment: There could be various reasons why the value changes to NA but difficult to exactly tell without a reproducible example. Can you share `dput(head(GDP_Brazil))` ?

Comment: At a guess, the data contains missing (`NA`) values. You can ignore them while doing the normalization by doing `min(Time, na.rm = TRUE)` and `max(Time, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the info. The data set does not contain N/As. The values are given for each year, that was actually the reason why I chose this data set.

```
dput(head(GDP_Brazil)
structure(list(`Series Name` = c("GDP (current US$ in billion)", 
"GDP (current US$ in billion)", "GDP (current US$ in billion)", 
"GDP (current US$ in billion)", "GDP (current US$ in billion)", 
"GDP (current US$ in billion)"), Time = c(1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 
1964, 1965), Brazil = c(15.1655699125199, 15.236854859469, 19.9262938390163, 
23.0214772922093, 21.2118922599904, 21.79003511719)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

it is a `tibble`.  so, we need either `[[` or `$` to subset, otherwise, it would still be a `tibble` with a single column.  This would have an effect when we do some calculations that require a `vector`

```
G <- GDP_Brazil[[3]]
Time <- GDP_Brazil[[2]]
```